# Prove that $\displaystyle\int_{x=-1}^{1}P_L(x)P_{L-1}\acute (x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{x=-1}^{1}P_L\acute(x)P_{L+1} (x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$

Tags: proof-writing, recurrence-relations, legendre-polynomials

A question (Problem $7.4$) in my textbook (Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences - 3rd Edition by Mary L. Boas [P578](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG0fi.png)) asks me to

> Use $$\int_{x=-1}^{1}(P_L(x)\cdot\text{any polynomial of degree < L})\,\mathrm{d}x=0\tag{A}$$ to prove that $$\displaystyle\int_{x=-1}^{1}P_L(x)P_{L-1}\acute (x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0\tag{1}$$and gives the hint: $\color{#180}{\fbox{What is the degree of $P_{L−1}(x)$}}$?
>
> Also, show that $$\displaystyle\int_{x=-1}^{1}P_L\acute(x)P_{L+1} (x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0\tag{2}$$

Where $P_L(x),P_{L-1}(x)$ represent any general Legendre Polynomial and $P_{L-1}\acute (x)$ is the derivative of the $(L-1)$th Legendre Polynomial.

---

I am genuinely stuck right from the beginning as equation $(\mathrm{A})$ doesn't say anything about whether derivatives can be used with it. In other words; if the question was asking me to "Show that $\displaystyle\int_{x=-1}^{1}P_L(x)P_{L-1} (x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$", then I would understand completely and simply quote equation $(\mathrm{A})$

I simply don't understand how to even start and the hint in $\color{#180}{\mathrm{green}}$ is making no sense to me whatsoever.

Does anyone have any idea how to show $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal to zero?

Many thanks.

Comment: Think of the polynomial $q(x) = P_{L-1}'(x)$. $P_{L-1}$ has degree $L-1$. What degree does $P_{L-1}'$ have?

Comment: @Cameron Does it also have degree $L-1$?

Comment: When you differentiate a (nonconstant) polynomial, its degree decreases by one, e.g. $x^n \Longrightarrow nx^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Cameron So it has degree $L-2$?

Comment: Yep. That is exactly right.

Comment: @Cameron Thank you so much, that's very helpful, so I can now see straight away that they are both automatically zero by $(\mathrm{A})$. Is this correct? If so would you consider making this as an answer then I can consider this question concluded (otherwise it will be left open)? (and I can give you some rep). There is [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747385/need-help-understanding-part-of-the-proof-that-displaystyle-int-x-11p-l) that relied on an answer to this question. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome. I have converted my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $q = P_{L-1}'$, then $q$ is a polynomial. Its degree is no greater than that of $P_{L-1}$ since differentiation can never increase the degree of a polynomial. However since $P_{L-1}$ is a polynomial of degree $L-1$, we have that $q$ has degree at most $L-1$. By $(\text{A})$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ follow.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe consider [this related one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747385/need-help-understanding-part-of-the-proof-that-displaystyle-int-x-11p-l) now? I appreciate your time.