# Stuck understanding proof $\int_{-1}^{1}P_n^2(x)dx=\frac{2}{2n+1}$ of Legendre Polynomials

Tags: legendre-polynomials

Skip past proof (i), I only included it because the proof following refers back to it. 
Below, I'm stuck on proof (ii), and the two ([one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747385/need-help-understanding-part-of-the-proof-that-displaystyle-int-x-11p-l),[two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334524/legendre-polynomials-proofs/765168#765168)) similar posts I found used Rodrigues' formula and a different formula. The red one below appears to come from $P_n=xP_{n-1}$ (I'm guessing so look at the formula and don't be mislead). Where did this $P_n$ come from. Likewise, where did the $P_{n-1}$ at the red 2 come from. Finally why are the right hand sides of the 2 equations before red 1 and red 2 equal?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try to add some details to the proof, so maybe you can understand better. From the Bonnet's recurrence relarions $$\left(n+1\right)P_{n+1}+nP_{n-1}=\left(2n+1\right)xP_{n}\tag{1}
 $$ $$nP_{n}+\left(n-1\right)P_{n-2}=\left(2n-1\right)xP_{n-1}\tag{2}
 $$ we observe that if we multiply $(1)$ by $P_{n-1}
 $ and $(2)$ by $P_{n}
 $ we have $$\left(n+1\right)P_{n+1}P_{n-1}+nP_{n-1}^{2}=\left(2n+1\right)xP_{n}P_{n-1}
 $$ $$nP_{n}^{2}+\left(n-1\right)P_{n-2}P_{n}=\left(2n-1\right)xP_{n-1}P_{n}
 $$ hence we have $$\left(n+1\right)\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n+1}\left(x\right)P_{n-1}\left(x\right)dx+n\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n-1}^{2}\left(x\right)dx=\left(2n+1\right)\int_{-1}^{1}xP_{n}\left(x\right)P_{n-1}\left(x\right)dx
 $$ $$n\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n}^{2}\left(x\right)dx+\left(n-1\right)\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n-2}\left(x\right)P_{n}\left(x\right)dx=\left(2n-1\right)\int_{-1}^{1}xP_{n}\left(x\right)P_{n-1}\left(x\right)dx
 $$ but from $(i)$ we know that $$\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n+1}\left(x\right)P_{n-1}\left(x\right)dx=\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n-2}\left(x\right)P_{n}\left(x\right)dx=0
 $$ so $$n\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n-1}^{2}\left(x\right)dx=\left(2n+1\right)\int_{-1}^{1}xP_{n}\left(x\right)P_{n-1}\left(x\right)dx\tag{3}
 $$ $$n\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n}^{2}\left(x\right)dx=\left(2n-1\right)\int_{-1}^{1}xP_{n}\left(x\right)P_{n-1}\left(x\right)dx\tag{4}
 $$ which is equivalent to $$\frac{n}{2n+1}\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n-1}^{2}\left(x\right)dx=\int_{-1}^{1}xP_{n}\left(x\right)P_{n-1}\left(x\right)\tag{5}
 $$ $$\frac{n}{2n-1}\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n}^{2}\left(x\right)dx=\int_{-1}^{1}xP_{n}\left(x\right)P_{n-1}\left(x\right)dx\tag{6}
 $$ and now we can observe that the RHS of $(5)$ and $(6)$ are equal, so $$\frac{n}{2n+1}\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n-1}^{2}\left(x\right)dx=\frac{n}{2n-1}\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n}^{2}\left(x\right)dx
 $$ $$\Leftrightarrow\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n}^{2}\left(x\right)dx=\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n-1}^{2}\left(x\right)dx
 $$ now we can conclude the proof by induction. Assume that $$\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n-1}^{2}\left(x\right)dx=\frac{2}{2n-1}
 $$ then $$\int_{-1}^{1}P_{n}^{2}\left(x\right)dx=\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\frac{1}{2n-1}=\frac{2}{2n+1}
 $$ and $$\int_{-1}^{1}P_{1}^{2}\left(x\right)dx=\frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: oh..., steps (5) and (6) were missing/misleading in the text. Polar coordinates used bessel series which had $\int x^vJ_{v-1}=x^vJ_v$ so I was thinking there might be a Legendre equivalent that might let me integrate the right of 5 and 6 by parts and get the next line. I wasn't looking at the next line as the left side.